# How to transform a requests function view to a class based view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use[this repository](https://github.com/buckyroberts/Spider) I found that is a Scraper and use it in Django to display the data obtained but I don't know how to do it using Django class based view and I have a small example using function views. Is it possible to do it using CBV?

Here is the snippet:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def dj_bs(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        website_link = request.POST.get('web_link', None)

        #requests
        url = website_link #url
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}#headers
        source=requests.get(url, headers=headers).text # url source
 
        #beautifulsoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
        h1_val = soup.h1.string #h1 value

        return render(request, 'django-bs.html', {'h1_val':h1_val})

    return render(request, 'django-bs.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class dj_bs(View):

    #runs when you hit get rquest
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        #render django-bs.html with empty context
        return render(request, "django-bs.html", context=context)

    #runs when you hit post method
    def post(self):
        website_link = self.request.POST.get('web_link', None)

        # requests
        url = website_link  # url
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) 
        Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}  # headers
        source = self.requests.get(url, headers=headers).text  # url source

        # beautifulsoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
        h1_val = soup.h1.string  # h1 value
        context = {'h1_val': h1_val}
        # render django-bs.html with h1_val
        return render(self.request, 'django-bs.html', context=context)
```

You can try this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
beautify = BeautifulSoup(source.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
h1_val = beautify.find('h1').get_text()
return render(request, 'django-bs.html', {'h1_val':h1_val})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Comment: I needed to transform the function view into a CBV